# How do I get logged out from social site in securesocial 2.1.3?

Tags: playframework-2.2, securesocial

In my play 2.2.4 application, using securesocial 2.1.3 module for authenticating the user via social login(google, facebook,linkedIn). Finally I want to logout the user from social site. For logout I use the following call.

```
      GET     /logout          securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout
```

But the social site is not get logged out.

what is this the correct way of doing logout?

Answer (score 0):

You can't log out from an external provider. That is not supported and I would advise against it. Your users won't expect to be logged out from Facebook for example if they decide to log out from your app.